# C++ Why diff EOF checks recommended for text vs numeric?

Tags: c++, eof

My textbook recommends using the member accessor method `iStreamVar.eof()` when dealing with textual data and `while (iStreamVar)` when dealing with numeric data.

Can someone please explain why it would matter?

Quote from book:

> Using the function eof to determine the end-of-file status works best if the input is text. The earlier method of determining the end-of-file status works best if the input consists of numeric data.

That is the only thing mentioned on the topic. After this, it just explains how the process works.

Comment: Does your textbook have any detail regarding why it makes those recommendations? A quote might be more helpful than your paraphrase.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added the relevant quote from the book.

Comment: The conversion operator of the stream to bool returns `!fail()` i.e. it is true if and only if neither the fail nor the bad bit are set; whether the eof bit is set simply doesn't matter. However in a real world program you'll want to do both checks: after each read operation you'll want to check, if the operation was successful in addition to using `eof` to check, if there's more input.

Comment: Thanks, @fabian. So would the idea be that the textbook suggests `while (iStreamVar)` because there might generally be more constraints on trying to read in numeric data? (e.g., A read-in of text might also want digits as char, but a read-in as numeric generally just wants numeric types?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which method you use for determining the end of data depends on how you use it. My guess is, both methods which your textbook mentions are used wrong, so they fail in different situations. That's why it recommends using different methods in different situations.

The correct method is not trivial, and it depends on how important error resilience is for you.

If you want to read a space-delimited stream with numbers in it, and you are sure the file contains no errors, the code is simplest:

```
int value;
while (iStreamVar >> value)
{
   ...
}
```

Note that it's not any of the two original options.

If your file contains space-delimited textual data, and you are sure there are no errors, use the same code (but declare the temporary variable as `string` instead of `int`).

If you want to detect and recover from errors, use more elaborate code. But I cannot recommend you any specific code structure - it depends on what exactly you want to do in case of errors. Also:

- Are text records delimited by space or newline?
- What if the input text-file contains an empty line?
- Numbers - floating-point or not?
- Numbers - if there is a stray character like `a` among number data, what to do?

So there is no single correct recipe for doing proper input with error resilience.

Comment: What do you mean "the file contains no errors"?  The contents of the file are irrelevant if there is a problem with the physical medium.  `read` errors happen regardless of the contents of the file.

Comment: By "errors" I mean bad data in the file. I disregarded I/O errors, but if you use the simplest code I wrote, any such error will end the loop and will be indistinguishable from end-of-file. This may be suboptimal, but is much better than infinite loop, which you can get if you use `eof()`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is something significant in the context that isn't shown in the question, that quote is nonsense.

The way to read from a file and check for success is to read from the file:

```
int data;
if (std::cin >> data)
    std::cout << "read succeeded, value is " << data << '\n';

std::string data;
if (std::cin >> data)
    std::cout << "read succeeded, value is " << data << '\n';

std::string data;
if (std::getline(std::cin, data)
    std::cout << "read succeeded, value is " << data << '\n';
```

If an attempted read **fails** you can call `.eof()` to find out whether the failure was because the input was at the end of the file. Contrary to what some beginners expect (and what some languages do), if `.eof()` returns false it does **not** mean that there is data remaining in the input stream. The stream might be **at** the end of the file after a successful read consumed the remaining input. `.eof()` will return false, but the next attempted read will fail, and after that, `.eof()` will return true.

```
std::stringstream input("1234");
int data;
input >> data; // succeeds
std::cout << input.eof() << '\n'; // outputs 0, no failure
input >> data; // fails, no more input
std::cout << input.eof() << '\n'; // outputs 1, failed because at end of file
```